# ¿Han existido pronombres personales átonos diferenciados para la primera y segunda persona, más allá de singular y plural?

Tags: gramática, historia, pronombres

El Diccionario panhispánico de dudas tiene un cuadro muy clarificador sobre los [pronombres personales átonos](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos):

> [image]

Luego dice:

> Como se ve en el cuadro, en las formas de primera y segunda persona solo se distingue entre singular y plural, y no existe una forma reflexiva específica: *Me gusta el cine* (no reflexivo) / *Me peino* (reflexivo). En la tercera persona existen formas distintas según el género, el número y la función sintáctica, así como una forma reflexiva específica, se (→ [se](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos?id=bsHtgs373D6sirfnKs), [1b](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos?id=bsHtgs373D6sirfnKs#1b), [c](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos?id=bsHtgs373D6sirfnKs#1c) y [d](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos?id=bsHtgs373D6sirfnKs#1d)), invariable en género y número: *Les gusta el cine* (no reflexivo) / *Se peinan* (reflexivo). La forma neutra lo se emplea cuando el antecedente es un pronombre neutro (esto, eso, aquello), toda una oración o el atributo en una oración copulativa: *Él no dijo eso, lo dije yo; Que no quieras ir, lo comprendo; —¿Eran guapas? —Sí, lo eran.*

Es curioso, pues, que la 3.ª persona tenga tanta variedad de pronombres personales átonos, mientras que la 1.ª y la 2.ª tengan apenas la variante singular/plural.

Por ello me surge la duda: ¿ha habido alguna variante más para la 1.ª y 2.ª personas en algún momento de la historia del castellano?

Comment: Que sepa, no.  Desde salir del romance han sido los que son ahora, y probablemente es porque no existe la misma posibilidad de confusión que permite la tercera persona.  No obstante, en la península, *sí* ha existido diferencia: en el asturiano oriental, han innovado formas diferenciadas en lo indirecto y singular: *dá**mi**lu / dói**ti**lu* (dámelo, te lo doy) frente a lo directo *llamó**me** / llamó**te*** (me/te llamó) o reflexivo *quéxo**me** / quéxes**te*** (me quejo, te quejas).

Comment: Supongo que la razón de que haya muchos más pronombres de tercera persona es que en tercera persona hay mucha más ambigüedad (la tercera persona puede ser cualquier persona o cosa) mientras que en primera y segunda persona no hay ambigüedad (siempre está claro a quién designan *yo* y *tú*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algunos dialectos voseantes emplean *os* (en lugar de *te*) en el [voseo reverencial](https://www.rae.es/dpd/voseo), por ejemplo en **Cuba**:

> La única excepción que se ha señalado en este siglo<sup>3</sup> al uso de estas formas pronominales de voseo en todo el vasto territorio americano es una pequeña zona
> del este de Cuba. Kany (1951: 90-91) afirma al respecto:
>
> > *Vos* appeared only in the interior of eastern Cuba, principally Camagüey, Bayamo and Manzanillo, but with a special form: it is here accompanied, not with the pronouns *te* and *tuyo* as elsewhere, but with the correct forms *os* and *vuestro*.
>
> - [*La constitución del paradigma pronominal de voseo*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/thesaurus/pdf/32/TH_32_002_015_0.pdf) (1977)

y en **Huánuco** (Perú):

> El voseo arequipeño queda inscrito en la tipología rioplatense de interlocución, el voseo huanuqueño (de mayor abolengo y ranciedad histórica que aquél) genera su propio patrón comunicativo. pues favorece la creación neta de un espacio interactivo claramente honorífico<sup>185</sup>.
>
> - [*Interpelación y espacios comunicativos*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dK_GPakJy74C&pg=PA219) (p.219)